# What's the most cost effective (reliable) way to establish a 200m ethernet link?

Tags: ethernet, repeater

As the title suggests, I have some kit which is 200m from our current infrastructure (outdoors).

What is the cheapest way to establish a reliable connection across a 200m stretch (Cat 5e ethernet only works up to about 100m from our tests)?

Comment: How much money do you want to spend? Is it possible that the cable may be attacked by animals or men with axes? I'd favor wireless.

Comment: Is it possible the wireless will be attacked by children with laptops?

Comment: Not mentioned yet in the answers: 1) Does it need to be electrically isolated -> fibre.  2) The reason why CAT5/6 length is limited is not only due to electrical reasons. There are also timeouts in the protocol which correspond with the time a signal needs to travel from one end of the cable to the other end of the cable.

Comment: We'd want to spend as little as possible (obviously) but it needs to be a reliable link. Wireless makes me nervous on the reliability front. The wireless would need to be secure (WPA should be fine) but shouldn't think we'll have to worry about men with axes or children with laptops as it's a fairly large / secured site.

Comment: It doesn't need to be electrically isolated (the attached devices will all be coming off the same supply).

Comment: You shouldn't have much to worry about for wireless reliability if there aren't any obstructions in-between the two links. The links are only 200m apart; wireless links work at miles apart. One concern may however be whether or not the frequencies are over-crowded in your area.

Comment: My other concern with using high gain antennas is that there's some sensitive gear in the areas which we'd be broadcasting the wireless signal. I'm not sure whether a wireless link trying to operate in the vicinity would be an issue or not, but it's worth considering I think... ?

Comment: 802.11n works at either 2.4GHz or 5GHz.  If you decide to go wireless I'd recommend using that to give you a double the number of channels to choose from.  In fact, since your spanning open space outdoors I'd recommend using 5GHz with highly directional antennas if you go wireless.  It will likely give you much higher throughput with the lowest probability of intercept.  And if you want to get really wide eyed, choose dual-channel MIMO WAPs with 15deg antennas.  That will give you performance very similar to 100Base-TX and a snooper would pretty much have to stand between your buildings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had to pull a run like you describe several times.  All three ways previously mentioned will work fine, but the critical issue you mentioned is cheap.

If you're extending a network where security is a real concern, this actually rules out wireless.  Adequate quality Wifi transceivers with matching outdoor rated directional antennae will run you upwards of $600 each.  If you don't care about security more than running WPA2-PSK you can hack it together with two cheap $50 WAPs and a DIY Cantenna on each end.

Copper will cost you $300 to $600.  Just to be safe, look for a box of Cat-5e with 24AWG solid conductors rated for moisture resistance.  Run your cables straight through plug to plug rather than punch and patch at the ends.  If you place a POE parent switch or power injector at one end you can place a 1port POE supported repeater in the middle.  I have used [this repeater](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833996073&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-NA-_-NA&gclid=CM-0lbea3rQCFYs7MgodnBEA-g) several times.  It's available from both Newegg and CDW for under $150 and will do fine outdoors if in a sheltered enclosure.  If you don't have a sheltered location in-between an outdoor rated equivalent will cost you $250-300.  Remember, only on end switch needs to transmit POE.

Fiber will cost $500 to $1000.  Outdoor rated 62.5/125 cable will cost you about $300 for 200m.  If you have an available WIC slot in the switches/routers at each end you can get the cards for under $150.  If not, your looking at $250-350 for a switch with a fibre port on each end putting the cost around $1000 mark.

Comment: PoE Injectors and extenders looks like a good fit for us - thanks!

Comment: I almost forgot to mention.  Check with an area electrician about ground differential between the buildings.  At 200m it's not likely to be of concern, but just in case.  It would suck to install it all then fry a switch when you plug it in.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously 200m is way out of range for CAT5e Ethernet. So you have three options really:

1. Have some active repeater in the middle. Maximum length for CAT5e Ethernet is 90m, so with 200m run you might have to have 2 repeaters (although if there are no bends, and you use quality cable and connectors, you might get away with 100m too.

   You can basically use any switch as a repeater. If you use PoE-powered switch, you will even not need to run a second cable for power. Of course, the switch must be rated for outside use (temperature/humidity), and it must be protected from elements, and you must have ways to access it for service if needed.
2. The second option is to use fiber optic. Of course, you'll have to have media converters on both ends (or switches with fiber-optic uplink), and laying fiber optic requires special tools/expertise. It might be more expensive than just use a repeater in the middle, but this solution will be more reliable.
3. The third option is to [go wireless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-range_Wi-Fi). Two Wi-Fi bridges with directional antennas can easily span 200m, if you have a clear line of sight. Of course, wireless has its own benefits and drawbacks. It might be cheaper than wired connection, but prone to electro-magnetic interference, has a bigger attack surface compared to a buried fiber-optic cable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. You didn't state any requirements as far a obstructions or digging cable into the ground. So:

- Fiber between the two locations: 2 transceivers (~$120 each) and 200m of cable (~$120) = ~$360
- Wireless links: 2 at ~$100 each = ~$200
- Switch or something halfway between to connect two ethernet cables: < $50

All of these are going to vary greatly in price and signal quality, depending on the quality of equipment you get and the installation methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would forget the repeaters and the wireless, just go with fibre. A nice 1000BASE-SX setup will work nicely. Fibre is reliable, fast, and this standard in particular is usually used for building to building connection, and therefore perfect for the distance you require.

Answer (score 0):

If you want twisted pair, 200m is perfectly fine for 2.5GBASE-T, as long as you used cable that's meant to do it. No, Cat 6 won't cut it. You'd need [something like Paige Datacom Gamechanger cable](https://paigedatacom.com/gamechanger). There may well be other vendors that sell similar 22AWG cable, but make sure you choose one that can warranty the connection, and let you certify it properly for being within specs expected by the IEEE-802.3 standards.

<sub>I'm not related in any way Paige Datacom, just familiar with their cable</sub>.