# Farm network, no power

Tags: networking

I would like to network a farm building which is 500' from my house. There are lots of trees between the two, so I doubt that wifi would work. 300' is the max length for Cat 5 ethernet cable.

What are my options? I could have a small solar panel and battery at the other end for power, but I don't have mains power there.

If there is a cabled solution I can trench to there and run cable through conduit.

Comment: You would need to use an outdoor switch, and configure the switch, to forward all traffic on one one port to all other ports.  This will allow you to run a cable around 300' then another run for the remaining distance.

Comment: How you run the cable is slightly out of scope so I won't get into details.

Comment: Do you currently have PoE (Power over Ethernet) on your network? If so, and the devices you use support PoE, you may be able to get buy without mains power. May I ask if it would be possible to have a halfway point where you could install a switch/repeater to boost the signal? That would cut the distance either way to 250 feet, which would be feasible. Or does it need to go directly there?

Comment: I guess for completeness we should mention that a distance like this can be easily covered by fiber, but this is above and beyond for a scenario like yours.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What's the most cost effective (reliable) way to establish a 200m ethernet link?](http://superuser.com/questions/532056/whats-the-most-cost-effective-reliable-way-to-establish-a-200m-ethernet-link), and/or [How to network two locations through 130m of trees](http://superuser.com/questions/616108/how-to-network-two-locations-through-130m-of-trees).

Comment: Also may want to look at [Running cat5 cable outdoors](http://superuser.com/questions/32903/running-cat5-cable-outdoors), and [Sharing LAN between two buildings. What should I use?](http://superuser.com/questions/536744/sharing-lan-between-two-buildings-what-should-i-use).

Comment: Thanks for the links, I wasn't able to find them when I originally searched. Having a POE repeater halfway sounds like a reasonable solution.